# How to create headers identical to PreferenceFragment category titles?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm writing my first Android application at the moment and I'm trying to maintain consistency. I've already implemented my own style of header for grouping input fields:

[image]

Now I've just implemented my PreferenceFragments and they put my header to shame! Is there a way to duplicate these headers automagically created by Android for the preference category titles?

[image]

Is this a built in widget, or is it just text styling with a separate View for the bar as I've done in my original header? If it is just styling, how do I achieve an identical look and feel?

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header_my_tasks"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/content_main_heading_my_tasks"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/header_my_tasks"
        android:text="Last updated 26/01/2014 15:11:04"/>
    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider_my_tasks"
        android:background="#CCC"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dip"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:layout_below="@id/header_my_tasks" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to work it out myself in the end. Just apply the following style to a TextView:

```
style="?android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
```

Answer (score 1):

The layout file for preference category in called `preferences_category_holo.xml` (see Android Source code). It uses style, which is called `Widget.TextView.ListSeparator`. Attribute is called `listSeparatorTextViewStyle`. I assume, if you apply this style to your `TextView` on the left hand side, then you should see same design. HEre is the style declaration from Android's `styles.xml` file.

```
<style name="Widget.TextView.ListSeparator">
    <item name="android:background">@android:drawable/dark_header_dither</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">?textColorSecondary</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical</item>
    <item name="android:paddingStart">8dip</item>
</style>
```